# How can I select Modal Dialog using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

How can I select  `window.showModalDialog()` in jquery?

In other words, I can select any element such as: DIVs, INPUTs and more in jQuery, but how can I select the regular javascript **ModalDialog** from jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe showModalDialog() prevents javascript from running in the parent window, which would not allow you to select it. Also, I don't know how great cross-browser support is for it. You may want to look into the modal dialog feature of jQueryUI which is far more dynamic. http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal